# Opengl slows down when a lot of stuff is on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

So I just started switching over from SDL to OpenGL today and I'm having this problem which I didn't have when I was using SDL.

When there's a lot of stuff on the screen the whole thing goes into slow motion. And when I say a lot I mean 200+ objects, but starts to be noticeable maybe from 50.

This is how things are rendered, I have a `class Renderable` with a `virtual void render()` which is called by the `RenderManager` in a loop `void manage()` which calls `render()` for every `Renderable` on screen.

The main loop looks like this

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

_renderManager.manage();

glFlush();
SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

and `render()` for the objects I'm using are only squares so

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// Draw square with colors
glEnd();
```

My CPU usage or memory usage don't seem to be high at all, it's just like... the game is slowing down.

Comment: you're going to need to narrow it down, or provide more code, or something, because there isn't really anything to go on here.

Comment: Have you tried just timing the individual components to see whats taking the most time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using immediate mode, you should use Vertex Arrays if you have performance problems.

We don't know all of your code so it's difficult to give a complete answer but using vertex arrays is surely the first step you should ensure if things go slowly.

Take a look here: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html

Basically the fact is that with `glBegin`...`glEnd` you end up doing many calls to the GPU while with vertex arrays you precompute your shapes, you save them in buffers and directly draw them reducing the number of calls by a significant amount.

Comment: Then you should provide something more or we can't help at all. How did you manage to switch from immediate to vertex arrays in 10 minutes? :)

Comment: The truth is there isn't much more to show. It's as simple as that right now, drawing a lot of rectangles on a screen. That code up there is the only opengl related code being called right now. I've never used opengl before, are there steps I'm missing here? That's why it took no time to switch to vertex arrays.

Comment: But how did you do that?  Did you create 10,000 vertex arrays, or just one with 10,000 vertices in it?  Are you updating the vertex array in your render loop, or applying a transform to each rectangle inside it?  Are you using instancing?  Do you have a vertex shader or a pixel shader? ... more information needed to help solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've never used OpenGL and I really had no idea what I was doing, but I've found a solution (and am working on it now!). Also thank you Jack for you answer! I'm definitely using vertex arrays now, I've found that glBegin() and glEnd() are deprecated. I might even try vertex buffer objects.

The problem was each individual `Renderable` was calling glBegin() and glEnd() when the `RenderManager` calls render() for each `Renderable` each loop. That causes a lot of stress for the GPU.

At the time of writing this answer I have a `sendVertices(GLfloat vertices[]);` in my `RenderManager` which adds all vertices to an `std::vector<GLfloat>`. During a loop for `RenderManager` I make a vertex pointer

`glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);`

then call

`glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices.size() / 2);`

So instead of rendering for each object it renders everything at once based on the vertices. Now I start to see slowing down at 800+ objects. Albeit not great, but there's still a lot of work I have to do. Because right now the `vertices` vector is recreated each loop rather than modified. Also this doesn't account for colors, but I'm on the right track!

Originally switching to vertex arrays it didn't make much of a difference because it was still being rendered for each individual object, so `glDrawArrays()` was being called for each of the 200+ `Renderable`.

EDIT:

Also sorry for not giving enough information, I guess I assumed the problem would be obvious. What confidence I have in myself, huh? Haha.